# How to properly setup FastSpring Popup Storefronts for Monthly and Yearly subscription?

Tags: javascript, html, payment-gateway, subscription

I am currently trying to use [FastSpring](https://fastspring.com) to sell subscription membership for my SaaS. I am trying to do this by implementing their [Popup Storefront](https://fastspring.com/docs/add-a-popup-storefront/) feature into my website's pricing page. What I wanted on this page is for users to be able to choose AND switch whether he/she wanted to subscribe to either Monthly or Yearly plan.

I was able to display and make the buttons to display the popups but somehow when/if I clicked both of the buttons, the checkout popup added the Monthly&Yearly pricing together instead of on or the other:

[image]

Here's my code that I have simplified to make it easier for someone to read and help out:

```
<script
    id="fsc-api"
    src="https://sbl.onfastspring.com/sbl/0.9.5/fastspring-builder.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"
    data-storefront="readermode.test.onfastspring.com/popup-readermode"
    data-continuous=true
>
</script>
<div class="container text-center">
    <br/><br/>

    <h1>Subcribe with Fastspring</h1>

    <br/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="pricing">
                <h3>Monthly Plan</h3><br/>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block" data-fsc-item-path-value='reader-mode-premium-monthly' data-fsc-action="Reset, Add, Checkout">Subscribe monthly</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="pricing">
                <h3>Yearly Plan</h3><br/>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-secondary btn-block" data-fsc-item-path-value='reader-mode-premium-yearly' data-fsc-action="Reset, Add, Checkout">Subscribe yearly</button>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this happens because of `data-continuous` flag is set. When you checkout monthly, and close the popup, and then choose yearly - both are selected, as the session with monthly is still active... I'm not sure, just guessing.